# gnuplot, format axis with constant power of 10

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a plot with values on the x axis ranging from 0 to 2 ms. I want to show a tick every .1 ms, with the labels going from 0.0, 0.1, ... up to 1.9, 2.0. I don't want to show the power at each tick, because I label the axis in ms, not in seconds. My data is given in seconds.

I can make this work using ($1*1000) to manually multiply the value by 1000

```
plot 'data.txt' using ($1*1000.0):3 w l lw 2
```

This does work. However, that method means I have to edit all my plots, which there are quite a few of. Also if I decide to change it later, I have to change all of them again. I would much rather make these settings in one config file.

I tried using the format specifier, e.g.

```
set format x "%1.1s"
```

But unfortunately I can't figure out how to specify a fixed power of 10 for it to use. The labels I get now are 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, ..., 9.0, 1.0, 1.1, ..., etc., instead of 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have a few questions:
1. Did you use the command `gnuplot` instead of `plot` ? When I install `gnuplot` it uses that as the command.
2. I get a syntax error with the parenthesis. Are you using `bash` ?
3. What should I put in a data.txt file to test my command?
4. Have you already referenced this for capital S? http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html

Comment: I think I solved it some other way, its over a year ago so I don't know exactly. To answer your questions: 1,2. this was part of a script that I executed by running `gnuplot filename` from a bash terminal. 3. I'm not sure what the data looked like; as I said, it's been over a year. 4. I don't think that solves the problem, although I haven't tested it. I have since stopped using gnuplot, I now prefer using matplotlib in python.